# C: Most efficient way to store variables where every bit matters

Tags: c, performance, storage

To start off: this might be a duplicate, but i can't seem to find a definitive answer on this question after having searched for it on google.

For a project i am designing a script that makes 2 ATMega328p chips communicate. At this moment i'm testing the best speed to do this, but my goal is to achieve really high baudrates. I have plenty of experience with making code efficient, but not with the memory management part. The problem:

I want to store a multiple of 8 bits (ex.: 48 bits). My first thought was to use an array of length 6 and type `uint8_t`, but I don't know how efficient arrays are compared to other types. Some people say pointers are more efficient and others say it doesn't matter, but I cant find a definitive answer on what the case is for really small amounts of memory. last quesion: I know the size of the sent bits will never be bigger than 64 bits, so would it matter if i just Always jused uint64_t?

Edit:
to clarify: My goal is to minimize the storage size, not the transmission size

Edit2:
What i meant by having a varying size: The size is determined on compile time, not while running the program.

Comment: What do you mean when you say pointers are more efficient ?

Comment: It depends on your hardware. Try to learn the machine language of these chips, you will understand the answer by yourself.

Comment: Arrays and pointers are often handled the same. For any array or pointer `a` and (valid) index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is equal to `*(a + i)`. So indexing using an array or a pointer in reality doesn't matter. However, the only way to be sure is to build one version of each (one pointer, one array) and build with optimization enable, and then compare the generated code.

Comment: 1) Do you want to optimize(minimize) storage size, or transmission size? 2) do all the objects have the same size?

Comment: Furthermore, if you would use a pointer, where would it point? To an array? Then what different would it be than use the array directly? Also, if you pass an array to a function it decays to a pointer to the first element, so even if you have an array somewhere, if it's passed to a function you still have pointers.

Comment: Lastly, if you have a pointer, you need to allocate space for the pointer variable besides the array, so size-wise using pointers is less efficient than using arrays.

Comment: [This](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2016/10/27/) might be of interest to you.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: Thats exactly why i thought it couldn't be more efficient

Comment: @wildplasser I want to optimize the storage size, the transmission size is already optimized (great name btw)

Comment: No, you can pack/unpack the data before/after transmission. Storage *may* have alignment requirements, and *may* favor particular sizes (powers of two, the smallest addressable size is a character anyway) Transmission *could* be performed on an arbitrary number of *bits*. (and CPU could be cheap, compared to memory and bandwidth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ATmega328p is a 8bit processor. All of its instructions are 8bit. Nothing will be faster than simply having an uint8_t array.

What you can do is, when you compile, look at your .lss file, it will show you the assmebly code, then you can look up the AVR instruction set and see the clock cycles each one will take. I think you will find using a uint64_t will just add unncessary overhead unless you are very careful with the way you are putting the bytes into it.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of your packages might vary, the most efficient approach would be to compress the package before communication.

For example the first 3 bits of each package, could determine the size of that package.

The compressed packages are communicated faster, and use up less memory space.

Comment: IMO you mean *packet*, not *package*